# Distribute $r$ indistinguishable balls randomly into $n$ cells. The probability that exactly $m$ cells will contain exactly $k$ balls each is?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions, inclusion-exclusion

Distribute $r$ indistinguishable balls randomly into $n$ cells.

The probability that exactly $m$ cells will contain exactly $k$ balls each is?

The answer:
$$\frac
{ m!r!}
{ m!n^{r} }  
\begin{equation}
\sum_{j}{\frac
{(n−j)^{r−jk}}
{(j−m)!(n−j)!(r−jk)!(k!)^{j}}}
\end{equation} $$
When then sum is for $$ j≥m $$  s.t. $$ j≤n,kj≤r $$

I tried to get to the above phrase without success, it is really a difficult exercise.